# how to access and change tcp configuration

Tags: networking

I wanna play the buffer size and other settings in the tcp configuration in order to finish the project that am working on and analyzed the results ??

I want to know if there is a file or something else that I can access to see and edit these settings and since am new to ubuntu I have no clue where to start so if you could please be informative in the answers I will appreciate that.

I have one more question is it different in fedora or is it the same as ubuntu ? because I have to do it on both OS

thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

It's the same. You can read/set most TCP/IP parameters with the `ifconfig` command. You can find out about which parameters by reading `man ifconfig`. You have to use `sudo` (or some other way of becoming `root`) to set. Also, I've found that the changed parameters take effect **ONLY** as the interface transitions from DOWN to UP (via `ifconfig`). There's also the `iwconfig` command for wireless parameters `man iwconfig`

Good luck with your assignment.